# iOS x Safariで画像が表示されない

Tags: ios, html, css, wordpress, safari

#### 前提・実現したいこと

以下のサイトのリリースを控えていますが、表題の不具合が解決できずに悩んでいます...
https://magazine.tabitatsu.jp/

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

iOSのSafariで記事ページにアクセスした際に、画像が表示されません。
https://magazine.tabitatsu.jp/articles/63

しかし、同じ端末で画面をリロードすると、以後表示されるようになります。

端末はiPhone5, iPhone6, iPad mini2で試しましたが何れも同様でした。
別のブラウザ、および別の端末(Android, Windows, Mac)ではこの現象は発生しませんでした。

#### 試したこと

- サーバーキャッシュのオフ => 効果無し
- ブラウザキャッシュのオフ、クリアー => 効果無し
- 画像の名前を日本語にした(最初はこの問題かと思いましたが、違いました)
- heightの固定値指定 => 表示される (autoだと表示されない)
- portrait <-> landscapeを切替 => 画像が表示される
- 別タスクに切替, しばらく放置, タスクをSafariに戻す => たまに表示される

丸1日試行錯誤していますが、解決できずにいます。
なにか心当たりのある方は、知恵をお貸しいただけると非常に助かります！
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「heightの固定値指定」というのが怪しい気はしますが、どこのheightのことなんでしょうか。とりあえず今は手元の5sで再現しませんでした。

Comment: @unaristaさん
ご確認ありがとうございます。いろいろと試してみたのですが、メディアクエリ+min-heightで対応することにしました。